# Why can't I import the page.py module in the PageObjects directory?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, python-import, importerror

I am following the flaskr tutorial so my code is similar to (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/). I am also following the Selenium PageObjects tutorial (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html).

```
flask_tutorial
├── flaskr
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── company_database.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── PageObjects
│   │   ├── element.py
│   │   ├── geckodriver.log
│   │   ├── locators.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   ├── page.py
│   │   └── README.ME
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── static
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── templates
│       ├── auth
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
├── instance
│   └── flask.sqlite
└── setup.py
```

At the beginning I am importing my PageObject main.py file; PythonOrgSearch class in flaskr/auth.py.

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

from .PageObjects.main import PythonOrgSearch
```

The PythonOrgSearch class imports page module.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

import page

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
```

Why can't it import the page.py module?

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nbosio1001/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 83, in find_best_app
    app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)
  File "/home/nbosio1001/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 119, in call_factory
    return app_factory()
  File "/home/nbosio1001/Documents/python/Fundamental_Analysis/app/flask_tutorial/flaskr/__init__.py", line 41, in create_app
    from . import auth
  File "/home/nbosio1001/Documents/python/Fundamental_Analysis/app/flask_tutorial/flaskr/auth.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .PageObjects.main import PythonOrgSearch
  File "/home/nbosio1001/Documents/python/Fundamental_Analysis/app/flask_tutorial/flaskr/PageObjects/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import page
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'page'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need an `__init__.py` file in the `PageObjects` directory.

Comment: I do that but it still gives me the same error.